# save the list to a excel file - with python code .?

Tags: python

I am new to python.
I want to save the list to a excel file. Will anyone be able to help with my code.

```
try:
    sqlite_cursor.execute(query)
    projects_data = sqlite_cursor.fetchall()

    projects = list()

    for row in projects_data:

        dict_temp = dict()

        dict_temp['GivenName'] = row[0]
        dict_temp['surname'] = row[1]
        dict_temp['DeptDesc'] = row[2]
        dict_temp['Region'] = row[3]
        dict_temp['LicType'] = row[4]
        dict_temp['LicClass'] = row[5]
        dict_temp['Licence_Number'] = row[6]
        dict_temp['License_Holder_Name'] = row[7]
        dict_temp['License_Description'] = row[8]
        dict_temp['LicStatus'] = row[9]
        dict_temp['Issue_Date'] = row[10]
        dict_temp['Expiry_Date'] = row[11]
      
    projects.append(dict_temp)

wb = Workbook() # creates a workbook object.
ws = wb.active # creates a worksheet object.

row_count = len(projects)

for row_count in projects:
    ws.append(row_count) # adds values to cells, each list is a new row.

    wb.save('Driver License.xlsx') # save to excel file.

except:

exit()
      

# Save Workbook

print('Save Workbook')
try:          
    wb.SaveAs(save_workbook)
except:
    close_out()
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install the `openpyxl` library:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Then, modify your code to use:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

try:
    sqlite_cursor.execute(query)

    projects_data = sqlite_cursor.fetchall()

    projects = []
    for row in projects_data:
        dict_temp = {
            'GivenName': row[0],
            'surname': row[1],
            'DeptDesc': row[2],
            'Region': row[3],
            'LicType': row[4],
            'LicClass': row[5],
            'Licence_Number': row[6],
            'License_Holder_Name': row[7],
            'License_Description': row[8],
            'LicStatus': row[9],
            'Issue_Date': row[10],
            'Expiry_Date': row[11],
        }
        projects.append(dict_temp)

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for project in projects:
        ws.append(project.values())

    wb.save('DriverLicense.xlsx')

    print('Excel file saved successfully.')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error occurred: {e}')
    # Handle the exception as needed
```

I was facing the same issue, and the `openpyxl` library helped me.